# php mysqli oo multi_query over an array

Tags: php, mysqli-multi-query

I have a $color_combo value which explodes into an array of $colors for a given item (3 values in the array). The $colors values are 3-character string codes i.e. FGR and there is a lookup table in the db that matches that code to the color 'forest green' ... but with 3 colors per item I need to run the query 3 times over the array:

```
 $color_combo = 'FGR-BLU-YLW'
 $colors = explode('-', $color_combo);
 $q = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT color_name from color_table as c WHERE color_code=?");
 $q->bind_param("s", $colors[]);
```

So I'm trying:

```
 while (mysqli_multi_query($link, $q)) {
 $result = mysqli_store_result($link))
 return $result;
 }
```

I'm haven't been able to find documentation on this case scenario, it might be using other functions ...:

```
 $value = $result->fetch_array(); ... or maybe next_result() or more_result()
```

My question at its core, is more about best practices with the mysqli extension and how to run queries on arrays of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code with the query into the following:

```
$color_combo = 'FGR-BLU-YLW'
$colors = explode('-', $color_combo);
$q = $mysqli ->prepare("
    SELECT 
        color_name 
    FROM
        color_table as c 
    WHERE 
        color_code IN (?, ?, ?)
");

$q->bind_param("sss", $colors[0], $colors[1], $colors[2]);
```

After executing the statement, the result will now contain 3 rows from the database containing the color names. You can loop over this result to retrieve the color names. The code assumes that there will always be 3 color codes in the $colors array.

Comment: Something else, from your profile I can see you haven't accepted any answers to your questions yet. You can do this by clicking the tick symbol next to the answer that worked for you. This makes it easier for other users that read your question to see which answer worked.